# Can a creature be grabbed by two different creatures at the same time?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, grapple, attack

I've been playing the Thunderspire Labyrinth adventure for D&D 4th edition, and at one point a character was grabbed by two different monsters.

Can two different creatures of different types grab and sustain a grab against the same creature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  It would be same two people holding/restraining you as long as both creatures want to cooperate.   If they are into cooperating then the character is going to have a tougher job breaking the grab of both.

If they are not into cooperating then if both grabs succeed there may be a check for the first 'grabber' resisting having it's 'grabee' stolen away.

Can you say bungee cord character?

Comment: This was in encounter W1: Chamber of the Well, in Thunderspire Labyrinth.  The creatures were a cavern choker and a phalagar, it seems like they might be smart enough to work together.

Comment: Agreed. Ouch.  Make a wish.

Answer (score 0):

If you're grabbed by multiple attackers, to escape you make an ordinary escape check, with +2 to the DC for every attacker beyond the first.  I don't have a page ref right on hand, but this happened with my group last weekend -- they were attacked by stirges (which were nasty!).